# Are class variables and static variables same in Java?

Tags: java, variables, static, static-variables, class-variables

I am aware that class variables are static and are shared among all the objects of that class. If that is the case, I am not sure what static variable is.

Furthermore, Wikipedia states class variables are not to be confused with static variables.

Comment: Same thing I believe: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: `Fields that have the static modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you ask for the difference between:

```
int a;
```

and

```
static int a;
```

if both are defined as class variables (they are not inside a method) the main practical differences are scope and lifetime.

A static variable will never be removed from memory and (if set public) will be accessible from anywhere in your project.

The main description of the static modifier is that it detaches from the class, so:

You don’t need to instantiate any object to use a static method.

You don’t need to instantiate any object to get a static variable.

You cant access non-static class variables inside a static method (basically you cant use "this")

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

From the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) @Zar gave in the comments,

> Fields that have the `static` modifier in their declaration are called static fields or class variables.

So the answer to your question is that, yes, in Java they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

static variables is also called as class variables. It is declared by using static modifier.
Only one copy of static variables are created for a class, so it is called as class variables.